# Shell string vs. integer comparison

Tags: bash, sh, zsh

I have found that if I have

```
time='9'
```

then

```
[ "$time" = 9 ]
[ "$time" = '9' ]
[ "$time" -eq 9 ]
[ "$time" -eq '9' ]
```

all eval true. This is unusual, since I am used to quotations depicting strings and no quotes being integers, and I had thought `-eq` is integer comparison and `=` is string. What is the explanation here?

I check this on `zsh`.

Comment: The shell does not work that way, since there are no actual data type unlike the general scripting languages. If you change the value of `time` to a string, then that is when the error occurs.

Comment: What do you mean change the value of time to a string @Jetchisel ?

Comment: like `time=foo`

Comment: Ah. Non digit characters -> so then I couldn't do integer comparison

Comment: Right, since the shell do quote removal, so quoting does not matter in your example. I'm not good at the details, hopefully someone can explain better.

Comment: `time` is the name of a command, don't also use it as the name of a variable to avoid obfuscating your code (at best).

Comment: Since the only data type known to your shell is _string_, _integer comparision_ means that both operands are interpreted in numeric context as a number, and the numbers are compared.

Comment: Quotes don't define strings; they *escape* strings in bulk. `'foo'` is exactly equivalent to `\f\o\o`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shell syntax works very differently from what you're used to. In the shell, pretty much everything is fundamentally a string; but if you use it in a context where a number is needed, the shell will try to parse that string into a number and use that (and then if there's a numeric result, it'll convert the result into a string for storage/display/whatever).

In the case of a `[ = ]` test, the strings are just compared directly. In `[ -eq ]`, they're converted to numbers and the numbers are compared. So, for example, `[ 05 = 5 ]` is false because "05" is not the same string as "5", but `[ "05" -eq "5" ]` is true because "05" and "5" both parse out to the same number.

Quoting doesn't affect this. What quoting does is change how the characters within the quoted section are parsed. The important thing with double-quoting variables is that it prevents the variable's value from being split into multiple words and/or wildcard-expanded into a list of matching filenames, both of which can cause chaos. zsh doesn't do this by default, so it's (*usually*) safe to leave the double-quotes off. But IMO double-quoting is still a good habit, since you won't necessarily always be in zsh.

Comment: I see, but then wouldn't something like `[ 4 -eq '0 4' ]` still be invalid?

Comment: Of course, just paste it in the command line to see the error `"-bash: [: 0 4: integer expression expected"` (`05` above is interpreted as an *octal* value `5` which is the same a decimal `5`)

Comment: @user129393192 Yes, because "0 4" isn't a valid number (i.e. the attempt to parse it into a number fails). But compare `[ '! 5' -eq 4 ]` (which gets a "integer expression expected" error) with `[ ! 5 -eq 4 ]` (which is true, because the `!` is taken as a negation operator rather than part of an invalid number). Lack of quoting can allow things to have completely different meanings from what you intended. The exact problems it can cause vary a lot with context, but in general it's a can of worms best left safely closed.

Comment: I see. Where is the best place to read on this stuff? I started to read the POSIX spec a couple months ago but began to find it a bit dreary, though I think I get the basic idea. Does stuff like operator precedence ( with the `!` and `-eq`) also vary from expectations (from C) ... what's the best source for this stuff would you say? I've typically learned languages from experience, googling and school in the past.

Comment: @user129393192 I don't know of good resources for zsh. For bash, I'd recommend Greycat's [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) and BashFAQ, and [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net), but they're all bash-only. As for precedence, in math it's pretty much what you expect, but for logical operators (*and* and *or*) it's weird and you should use explicit grouping (and don't even try complex expressions inside `[ ] ` -- the syntax there is actually ambiguous).

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html might help

Comment: @Jetchisel it isn't exactly like C though, unless I'm mistaken. `[ ! 2 -eq 2 ]` seems to apply the `!` to the entire equality and returns false, whereas `! 2 == 2` in C would only apply it on the LHS.

Comment: BTW, I should correct my original note about double-quoting variables, since it doesn't really apply in zsh. The old Bourne (I think it was) shell did word splitting and wildcard expansion unless you used double-quotes, and most modern shells do the same for compatibility (even though it's generally regarded as a source of trouble). zsh, on the other hand, disables these by default, so it's (*usually*) safe to leave variable references naked in zsh. Usually.

Comment: @user129393192 : For that part of the shell problems you are refering here, `man test` would provide the necessary explanation, but in the future, please make up your mind, whether you are interested in sh, or bash, or zsh. Since you make to me the impression of a beginner in these matters, learning three shell  languages in parallel could be too much and confusing.